# Has anyone got ApplicationInsights working with WinUI?

Tags: logging, winui

I've got a WinUI application that has published for months on the Windows Store with no problem. In the last week, it's been rejected several times with no feedback other than 'Crashes on start'. The application runs just fine from my machine and passes certification, so I need some more feedback why it's crashing during the store evaluation. So, my first thought was logging, but I can't seem to get Application Insights to work. Here's the code:

```
    this.serviceProvider = serviceCollection
        .AddSingleton(this.configuration)
        .AddLogging(lb => lb.AddApplicationInsights(
            tc =>
            {
                tc.DisableTelemetry = this.configuration.GetValue("ApplicationInsights:DisableTelemetry", true);
                tc.ConnectionString = this.configuration.GetValue("ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString", Guid.Empty.ToString());
            },
            ailo => { }))
        .AddLocalization()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
```

And here's the settings:

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "DisableTelemetry":  true,
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=20fafaa0-aeef-4ce9-927d-47b9df47e479"
  }
}
```

Nothing shows up in the log when I call:

```
    // Log a progress indication message.
    ILogger logger = this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<App>>();
    logger.LogError("{message}", $"Launching {packageInfo.Name}, {packageInfo.Version}.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [Application Insights for Worker Service applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service) since it's more suited for console applications without a Http context.

Example:

```
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(options =>
  {
      options.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=<YOURKEY>";
  });
```

This works for my WinUI3 / Windows App SDK v1.3